# Weakening vinyl's RecAll constraint through entailment

Tags: haskell, constraints, ghc, vinyl

In the [vinyl](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vinyl) library, there is a `RecAll` type family, which let's us ask that a partially applied constraint is true for every type in a type level list. For example, we can write this:

```
myShowFunc :: RecAll f rs Show => Rec f rs -> String
```

And that's all lovely. Now, if we have the constraint `RecAll f rs c` where `c` is unknown, and we know the `c x` entails `d x` (to borrow language from ekmett's [contstraints](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints) package), how can we get `RecAll f rs d`?

The reason I ask is that I'm working with records in some functions that require satisfying several typeclass constraints. To do this, I am using the `:&:` combinator from the [Control.Constraints.Combine](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/exists-0.2/docs/Control-Constraint-Combine.html) module in the [exists](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/exists-0.2) package. (Note: the package won't build if you have other things installed because it depends on a super-old version of `contravariant`. You can just copy the one module I mentioned though.) With this, I can get some really beautiful constraints while minimizing typeclass broilerplate. For example:

```
RecAll f rs (TypeableKey :&: FromJSON :&: TypeableVal) => Rec f rs -> Value
```

But, inside the body of this function, I call another function that demands a weaker constraint. It might look like this:

```
RecAll f rs (TypeableKey :&: TypeableVal) => Rec f rs -> Value
```

GHC can't see that the second statement follows from the first. I assumed that would be the case. What I can't see is how to prove it for reify it and help GHC out. So far, I've got this:

```
import Data.Constraint

weakenAnd1 :: ((a :&: b) c) :- a c                                                                    
weakenAnd1 = Sub Dict -- not the Dict from vinyl. ekmett's Dict.

weakenAnd2 :: ((a :&: b) c) :- b c                                                                    
weakenAnd2 = Sub Dict
```

These work fine. But this is where I am stuck:

```
-- The two Proxy args are to stop GHC from complaining about AmbiguousTypes
weakenRecAll :: Proxy f -> Proxy rs -> (a c :- b c) -> (RecAll f rs a :- RecAll f rs b)
weakenRecAll _ _ (Sub Dict) = Sub Dict
```

This does not compile. Is anyone aware of a way to get the effect I am looking for. Here are the errors if they are helpful. Also, I have `Dict` as a qualified import in my actual code, so that's why it mentions `Constraint.Dict`:

```
Table.hs:76:23:
    Could not deduce (a c) arising from a pattern
    Relevant bindings include
      weakenRecAll :: Proxy f
                      -> Proxy rs -> (a c :- b c) -> RecAll f rs a :- RecAll f rs b
        (bound at Table.hs:76:1)
    In the pattern: Constraint.Dict
    In the pattern: Sub Constraint.Dict
    In an equation for ‘weakenRecAll’:
        weakenRecAll _ _ (Sub Constraint.Dict) = Sub Constraint.Dict

Table.hs:76:46:
    Could not deduce (RecAll f rs b)
      arising from a use of ‘Constraint.Dict’
    from the context (b c)
      bound by a pattern with constructor
                 Constraint.Dict :: forall (a :: Constraint).
                                    (a) =>
                                    Constraint.Dict a,
               in an equation for ‘weakenRecAll’
      at Table.hs:76:23-37
    or from (RecAll f rs a)
      bound by a type expected by the context:
                 (RecAll f rs a) => Constraint.Dict (RecAll f rs b)
      at Table.hs:76:42-60
    Relevant bindings include
      weakenRecAll :: Proxy f
                      -> Proxy rs -> (a c :- b c) -> RecAll f rs a :- RecAll f rs b
        (bound at Table.hs:76:1)
    In the first argument of ‘Sub’, namely ‘Constraint.Dict’
    In the expression: Sub Constraint.Dict
    In an equation for ‘weakenRecAll’:
        weakenRecAll _ _ (Sub Constraint.Dict) = Sub Constraint.Dict
```

Comment: I think at least part of the problem is that the `c` is quantified in the wrong place...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's begin by reviewing how `Dict` and `(:-)` are meant to be used.

```
ordToEq :: Dict (Ord a) -> Dict (Eq a)
ordToEq Dict = Dict
```

Pattern matching on a value `Dict` of type `Dict (Ord a)` brings the constraint `Ord a` into scope, from which `Eq a` can be deduced (because `Eq` is a superclass of `Ord`), so `Dict :: Dict (Eq a)` is well-typed.

```
ordEntailsEq :: Ord a :- Eq a
ordEntailsEq = Sub Dict
```

Similarly, `Sub` brings its input constraint into scope for the duration of its argument, allowing this `Dict :: Dict (Eq a)` to be well-typed as well.

However, whereas pattern-matching on `Dict` brings a constraint into scope, pattern-matching on `Sub Dict` does not bring into scope some new constraint conversion rule. In fact, unless the input constraint is already in scope, you can't pattern-match on `Sub Dict` at all.

```
-- Could not deduce (Ord a) arising from a pattern
constZero :: Ord a :- Eq a -> Int
constZero (Sub Dict) = 0

-- okay
constZero' :: Ord a => Ord a :- Eq a -> Int
constZero' (Sub Dict) = 0
```

So that explains your first type error, `"Could not deduce (a c) arising from a pattern"`: you have tried to pattern-match on `Sub Dict`, but the input constraint `a c` was not already in scope.

The other type error, of course, is saying that the constraints you did manage to get into scope were not sufficient to satisfy the `RecAll f rs b` constraint. So, which pieces are needed, and which ones are missing? Let's look at the definition of `RecAll`.

```
type family RecAll f rs c :: Constraint where
  RecAll f [] c = ()     
  RecAll f (r : rs) c = (c (f r), RecAll f rs c)
```

Aha! `RecAll` is a type family, so unevaluated as it is, with a completely abstract `rs`, the constraint `RecAll f rs c` is a black box which could not be satisfied from any set of smaller pieces. Once we specialize `rs` to `[]` or `(r : rs)`, it becomes clear which pieces we need:

```
recAllNil :: Dict (RecAll f '[] c)
recAllNil = Dict

recAllCons :: p rs
           -> Dict (c (f r))
           -> Dict (RecAll f rs c)
           -> Dict (RecAll f (r ': rs) c)
recAllCons _ Dict Dict = Dict
```

I'm using `p rs` instead of `Proxy rs` because it's more flexible: if I had a `Rec f rs`, for instance I could use that as my proxy with `p ~ Rec f`.

Next, let's implement a version of the above with `(:-)` instead of `Dict`:

```
weakenNil :: RecAll f '[] c1 :- RecAll f '[] c2
weakenNil = Sub Dict

weakenCons :: p rs
           -> c1 (f r) :- c2 (f r)
           -> RecAll f rs c1 :- RecAll f rs c2
           -> RecAll f (r ': rs) c1 :- RecAll f (r ': rs) c2
weakenCons _ entailsF entailsR = Sub $ case (entailsF, entailsR) of
    (Sub Dict, Sub Dict) -> Dict
```

`Sub` brings its input constraint `RecAll f (r ': rs) c1` into scope for the duration of its argument, which we've arranged to include the rest of the function's body. The equation for the type family `RecAll f (r ': rs) c1` expands to `(c1 (f r), RecAll f rs c1)`, which are thus both brought into scope as well. The fact that they are in scope allows us to pattern-match on the two `Sub Dict`, and those two `Dict` bring their respective constraints into scope: `c2 (f r)`, and `RecAll f rs c2`. Those two are precisely what the target constraint `RecAll f (r ': rs) c2` expands to, so our `Dict` right-hand side is well-typed.

To complete our implementation of `weakenAllRec`, we will need to pattern-match on `rs` in order to determine whether to delegate the work to `weakenNil` or `weakenCons`. But since `rs` is at the type level, we cannot pattern-match on it directly. The [Hasochism](https://personal.cis.strath.ac.uk/conor.mcbride/pub/hasochism.pdf) paper explains how in order to pattern-match on a type-level `Nat`, we need to create a wrapper datatype `Natty`. The way in which `Natty` works is that each of its constructors is indexed by a corresponding `Nat` constructor, so when we pattern-match on a `Natty` constructor at the value level, the corresponding constructor is implied at the type level as well. We could define such a wrapper for type-level lists such as `rs`, but it just so happens that `Rec f rs` already has constructors corresponding to `[]` and `(:)`, and the callers of `weakenAllRec` are likely to have one lying around anyway.

```
weakenRecAll :: Rec f rs
             -> (forall a. c1 a :- c2 a)
             -> RecAll f rs c1 :- RecAll f rs c2
weakenRecAll RNil       entails = weakenNil
weakenRecAll (fx :& rs) entails = weakenCons rs entails
                                $ weakenRecAll rs entails
```

Note that the type of `entails` must be `forall a. c1 a :- c2 a`, not merely `c1 a :- c2 a`, because we don't want to claim that `weakenRecAll` will work for any `a` of the caller's choosing, but rather, we want to require the caller to prove that `c1 a` entails `c2 a` for every `a`.